# krajee bootstrap file input

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I'm using the plugins krajee bootstrap file input. [web site](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input)

I want to just send a photo to the server.
after sending the photo to the server with ajax, the server returns me a message json.
if the server response and success, I want to disable the button of the input file, and show only the delete button.
how should I do?
I tried but it does not work well.

```
$("#file-1").fileinput({
uploadAsync: false,
uploadUrl: 'o.php', 
allowedFileExtensions : ['jpg', 'png','gif'],
overwriteInitial: false,
maxFileSize: 1000,
maxFilesNum: 10,
MAXFILECOUNT:1,
//allowedFileTypes: ['image', 'video', 'flash'], 
slugCallback: function(filename) {
return filename.replace('(', '_').replace(']', '_');

}

}).on('fileuploaded', function(event, data, previewId, index) {
$('#file-1').fileinput('disable');
});
```

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435550/jquery-submit-disable-input-file

Answer (score 2):

Use 'filebatchuploadsuccess' instead of 'fileuploaded'

```
.on('filebatchuploadsuccess', function(event, data) {
  $('#file-1').fileinput('disable');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `"filebatchuploadcomplete"` event to trigger upload complete. This will run either fails or successes:

```
$('#file-1').on('filebatchuploadcomplete', function(event, files, extra) {
    $('#file-1').fileinput('disable');
});
```